# How to divide a polar plot into 12 partitions?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I have different datapoints for every day in a year and want to plot them into a polar plot and instead of having the degrees as labels, I want to have the 12 month. That is what I tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = list(range(1,366))
theta = [i* 2 * np.pi / 365  for i in theta]
radii=np.random.rand(365)

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_xticklabels(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
```

The result looks as follows:

[image: Result]

But how can I divide the plot into 12 parts, s.t. I can have 12 labels?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/projections_api.html#matplotlib.projections.polar.PolarAxes.set_thetagrids

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find it first...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, already found an answer. I have to insert a

```
    lines, labels = plt.thetagrids((0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330), labels=('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'), fmt=None)
```

to get

[ResultWith12Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTWtW.png)